# MPSCNN Weight Ordering

Tags: ios, swift, neural-network, conv-neural-network, metal

The Metal Performance Shader framework provides support for building your own Convolutional Neural Nets. When creating for instance an `MSPCNNConvolution` it requires a 4D weight tensor as `init` parameter that is represented as a 1D float pointer.

```
init(device: MTLDevice,
  convolutionDescriptor: MPSCNNConvolutionDescriptor,
  kernelWeights: UnsafePointer<Float>,
  biasTerms: UnsafePointer<Float>?,
  flags: MPSCNNConvolutionFlags)
```

The documentation has this to say about the 4D tensor

> The layout of the filter weight is arranged so that it can be
>   reinterpreted as a 4D tensor (array)
>   weight[outputChannels][kernelHeight][kernelWidth][inputChannels/groups]

Unfortunately that information doesn't really tell me how to arrange a 4D array into a one dimensional `Float` pointer.

I tried ordering the weights like the `BNNS` counterpart requires it, but without luck.

How do I properly represent the 4D tensor (array) as a 1D `Float` pointer (array)?

*PS: I tried arranging it like a C array and getting the pointer to the flat array, but it didn't work.*

**UPDATE**

@RhythmicFistman: That's how I stored it in a plain array, which I can convert to a `UsafePointer<Float>` (but doesn't work):

```
var output = Array<Float>(repeating: 0, count: weights.count)

for o in 0..<outputChannels {
    for ky in 0..<kernelHeight {
        for kx in 0..<kernelWidth {
            for i in 0..<inputChannels {
                let offset = ((o * kernelHeight + ky) * kernelWidth + kx) * inputChannels + i
                output[offset] = ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how you made the 4D to 1D attempt? barring using the wrong pointer, I think the only other thing that can go wrong is the order of the indices.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Updated the question, the problem is not even Apples OWN example project (with their own trained weights) works correctly. So how am I supposed to know whats even wrong... my data or their implementation.

Comment: Which Apple sample are you referring to? Both MetalImageRecognition and  MPSCNNHelloWorld seem to work for me with Xcode 8.2 beta and iOS 10.2 beta.

Comment: @warrenm try to run the deep net on the MNIST set in MPSCNNHelloWorld (toggle the button at the bottom to use deep net and start the test run on the mnist set). It will result in 7 or 8% accuracy which cant be correct.

Comment: See example of `tf.transpose` here: http://www.mattrajca.com/2016/11/26/speeding-up-tensorflow-with-metal-performance-shaders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. Here are the 2 python functions I use to reform my convolutions and fully connected matrices

```
# shape required for MPSCNN [oC kH kW iC]
# tensorflow order is [kH kW iC oC]
def convshape(a):
    a = np.swapaxes(a, 2, 3)
    a = np.swapaxes(a, 1, 2)
    a = np.swapaxes(a, 0, 1)
    return a

# fully connected only requires a x/y swap
def fullshape(a):
    a = np.swapaxes(a, 0, 1)
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something I recently had to do for Caffe weights, so I can provide the Swift implementation for how I reordered those. The following function takes in a Float array of Caffe weights for a convolution (in [c_o][c_i][h][w] order) and reorders those to what Metal expects ([c_o][h][w][c_i] order):

```
public func convertCaffeWeightsToMPS(_ weights:[Float], kernelSize:(width:Int, height:Int), inputChannels:Int, outputChannels:Int, groups:Int) -> [Float] {

    var weightArray:[Float] = Array(repeating:0.0, count:weights.count)
    var outputIndex = 0

    let groupedInputChannels = inputChannels / groups
    let outputChannelWidth = groupedInputChannels * kernelSize.width * kernelSize.height

    // MPS ordering: [c_o][h][w][c_i]
    for outputChannel in 0..<outputChannels {
        for heightInKernel in 0..<kernelSize.height {
            for widthInKernel in 0..<kernelSize.width {
                for inputChannel in 0..<groupedInputChannels {
                    // Caffe ordering: [c_o][c_i][h][w]
                    let calculatedIndex = outputChannel * outputChannelWidth + inputChannel * kernelSize.width * kernelSize.height + heightInKernel * kernelSize.width + widthInKernel
                    weightArray[outputIndex] = weights[calculatedIndex]
                    outputIndex += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return weightArray
}
```

Based on my layer visualization, this seems to generate the correct convolution results (matching those produced by Caffe). I believe it also properly takes grouping into account, but I need to verify that.

Tensorflow has a different ordering than Caffe, but you should be able to change the math in the inner part of the loop to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation here assumes some expertise in C. In that context, a[x][y][z] is typically collapsed into a 1-d array when x, y and z are constants known at compile time.   When this happens, the z component varies most quickly, followed by y, followed by x -- outside in.

If we have a[2][2][2], it is collapsed to 1D as:

```
{ a[0][0][0], a[0][0][1], a[0][1][0], a[0][1][1], 
  a[1][0][0], a[1][0][1], a[1][1][0], a[1][1][1] }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think tensorflow already has a convenient method for such task:

```
tf.transpose(aWeightTensor, perm=[3, 0, 1, 2])
```

Full documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose